# Getting the last 5 digits of the Microsoft Office product key with a script

Tags: windows, batch, microsoft-office, script

When running the command `cscript "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\OSPP.VBS" /dstatus` you get the following output (keys hidden for privacy):

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.812
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
 
---Processing--------------------------
---------------------------------------
PRODUCT ID: 00403-90046-04636-AAOEM
SKU ID: 1ba73ccc-3b8a-42b7-9936-0fb1863ea6ec
LICENSE NAME: Office 19, Office19HomeBusiness2019R_OEM_Perp edition
LICENSE DESCRIPTION: Office 19, RETAIL channel
LICENSE STATUS:  ---LICENSED--- 
Last 5 characters of installed product key: XXXXX
---------------------------------------
PRODUCT ID: 00200-70000-00000-AA691
SKU ID: d7279dd0-e175-49fe-a623-8fc2fc00afc4
LICENSE NAME: Office 16, Office16O365HomePremR_Grace edition
LICENSE DESCRIPTION: Office 16, RETAIL(Grace) channel
LICENSE STATUS:  ---NOTIFICATIONS--- 
ERROR CODE: 0xC004F009
ERROR DESCRIPTION: The Software Licensing Service reported that the grace period expired.
Last 5 characters of installed product key: XXXXX
---------------------------------------
---------------------------------------
---Exiting-----------------------------
```

I am trying to grab the five digits of the product key out of the command output so I can run it across a lot of devices. I have this script that works great except it grabs the product key for the grace period instead of the actual license. I was playing around with it and trying to get it to grab the line directly after the one that says "LICENSED" but couldn't figure it out.

What I have so far:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%G IN ('cscript "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\OSPP.VBS" /dstatus ^| findstr /C:"Last 5 characters of installed product key:"') do ( set "key=%%G" )
set "key=%key: =%"
echo %key%
```

Answer (score 0):

These commands inside a `.bat` file will set the environment variable
`last` to the last 5 characters:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%I in ('cscript "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\OSPP.VBS" /dstatus ^| findstr /B "Last 5 characters of installed product key"') do for %%A in (%%~I) do set last=%%A
echo %last%
```

Comment: This seems to produce the same result as my script does... I am trying to get the key XXXXX that comes after the line which contains "LICENSE STATUS:  ---LICENSED--- "

Comment: It works in my test. I'm not getting it from the same line as you, but from the last line that says "Last 5 characters of installed product key".

Answer (score 0):

```all-bat
@echo off

for /f tokens^=2delims^=: %%i in ('
    cscript "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office16\OSPP.VBS" /dstatus ^| find /i "key:"
   ')do set "_key=%%~i" && call set "_key=%%_key: =%%" && goto %:^)


%:ˆ)
echo\%_key%
```

---

Try using `call set "_key=%%_key: =%%"` and `&& goto :label`

Comment: This seems to produce the same result as my script